# Json error on jQuery's load method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following error when playing with JSON request:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

This is the jQuery code:

```
//load partial view contain grid
$('#rptProductsRates').load('@Url.Action("ProductsRatesFlipPagination", "Reports")', { flipPagination: true }, function (data) {
    if (data.toString().substr(0, 15) == "<!DOCTYPE html>") {
      window.location = '@Url.Action("ProductsRates", "Reports")';
    }    
    else {
            debugger;
            var resultError = data.toString().substr(0, 9);
            if (resultError == "<!DOCTYPE") {
               var exceptionURL='@Url.Content("~/Reports/Exception?controller=Reports&action=ProductsRates")';
                        window.location = exceptionURL;
                //unblock the UI     
                $.unblockUI();
            }
            else {
                $('#contentDiv').show();
                //unblock the UI     
                $.unblockUI();
                var bottomMarginFirst = (screen.height * .29)
                var bottomMargin = (screen.height * .42)
                if ($('.renderBody').height() <= ($(document).height() - bottomMarginFirst)) {
                    $('.renderBody').css({ 'height': ($(document).height() - bottomMargin + @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GridHeight"] - 100) })
                }
            }
    }
```

What's the cause and a possible solution to this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're throwing an AJAX request back to a an ASP.NET MVC3 back-end. AFAIK, the native Javascript serializer used by MVC3 has a **default** maximum parsed JSON length of 4MB (correct me if I'm mistaken). If you're passing in a JSON string larger than that, you'll have to slap on a workaround (by breaking up the request, optimizing your objects, or tweaking your server-side settings).

Comment: yes you are correct, from back end I have 6885 records and with 15 columns. I think 4MB thing applies here...Is there any way to check and the size of JSON string??

Comment: Not really sure how to do that, but with a data payload of that size, I'd say you're definitely going over. If you're not performing a data buffet, you may want to probably consider AJAX request pooling? Pull out the records in sequential batches across multiple AJAX calls.

Comment: link is,  http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/large-json-result-for-teleriks-mvc-grid/